# How can I connect a Google G1 to Windows Vista via Bluetooth?

Tags: windows-vista, bluetooth

My question is mainly about getting the phone connected to Vista computer.

Once it's connected I want to share the internet connection with PdaNet.

Does anyone know how to tether with Vista using bluetooth?

Comment: I don't think internet tethering is either supported nor really possible. Even though you're trying to connect your phone to your computer, I consider this question off-topic and advice you to ask it on ForceClose.com (http://www.forceclose.com/questions)

Comment: If the community disagrees, feel free to comment/flag or vote to reopen

Comment: @Ivo - it's exactly in the grey area, so I guess we should refer to the simple "smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer" from the FAQ. The question is really on the "interfacing", so I guess we could leave it opened. But for sure there are better places to ask for it, and I doubt it will get correct a lot of answers here.

Comment: The question is mainly about getting the phone connected to Vista computer. Once it's connected I can try the internet sharing with PdaNet software.

Comment: There you go @Gnoupi

Comment: Check out the [bluetooth-tethering](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-tethering) tag at [android.se].